# Is chemical equilibrium possible at any temperature and pressure?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, thermodynamics, equilibrium, free-energy, reaction-control

Consider the chemical reaction ${\rm Na+Cl\to NaCl}$ by mixing ${\rm Na}$ with ${\rm Cl}$ (or by mixing ${\rm NaOH}$ with some acid). This process is exothermic while the reverse ${\rm NaCl\to Na+Cl}$ must be endothermic. Can these two processes exist in chemical equilibrium (by which I understand equal rates for forward and reverse reaction) at any temperature and pressure?

I'm from the physics background. Please bear with my naive question.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86052/relating-the-reversibility-of-equilibrium-to-that-of-thermodynamics. This question and answer should really enlighten you. Note also that your reaction should be $\ce{2 Na + Cl2 -> 2NaCl}$.